# underscore.js has() does not work with nested properties?

Tags: underscore.js

Why does the following return `false`:

```
var o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: { 
    d: 10, 
    e: 20 
  }
}

_.has(o, "d")
```

_.has() will not work with nested properties, i.e., properties from nested objects ?!

Comment: You surely want to use `_.has`, not `_has.`!

Comment: `_has(…)` will run into a different problem - that the function doesn't exist. `.has` is a method of the `_` object.

Comment: @Bergi: wow, that was... ugly  :) In any case, _has(o, "d") returns false - `has` will not work with nested properties ?!

Comment: No, it won't. Why should it? The `o` object only has three keys (`a`, `b`, `c`), plus maybe some inherited ones, but it does not have `d` or `e` properties.

Comment: You are right, but...  i think the API should provide an option to get the "inherited" ones. All right, does not, does not.

Comment: You can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for that, it considers inherited properties as well (e.g. `"hasOwnProperty" in {}` yields `true`). However, there is no API to get properties that are nested in other objects.

Comment: @Bergi: I do not see this happening. `"d" in o` returns false. `"a" in o` returns true.

Comment: I didn't say that `o` inherits a `d` property. It does inherit from `Object.prototype`, which has no `d` property. You're looking for *nested* properties, not *inherited* ones.

Answer (score 1):

_.has(object, key) is a shortcut to the javascript object.hasOwnProperty(key) and it's not recursive. So that won't work that way.

It could be implemented like that though :

```
a = {
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : {
        "d":4,
        "e":5,
        "f":{
            "g":7,
            "h":8
        }
    }
};

// hasr => has recursive
_.hasr = function(object, key){
    if (_.has(object, key)){
        return true;
    }else{
        if(object instanceof Object){
            for(subobject in object){
                var recursive = _.hasr(object[subobject], key)
                if(recursive){
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};


console.log(_.hasr(a, "a")); // Return true
console.log(_.hasr(a, "b")); // Return true
console.log(_.hasr(a, "c")); // Return true
console.log(_.hasr(a, "d")); // Return true
console.log(_.hasr(a, "e")); // Return true
console.log(_.hasr(a, "f")); // Return true
console.log(_.hasr(a, "g")); // Return true
console.log(_.hasr(a, "h")); // Return true
console.log(_.hasr(a, "i")); // Return false
console.log(_.hasr(a, "j")); // Return false
```

Comment: Khopa, the implementation is not the problem, I just wanted to make sure _.has() does not check inherited properties. I don't know, I think this feature should have been provided in the API.

Comment: @Veverke: I don't know, why do you think that? Recursive traversals of generic objects quickly gets out of hand.

Comment: What do you mean with "gets out of hand" ? I am just saying that I think this requirement is quite common hence it would be useful to include it in an API such as underscore. I am actually quite surprised with "there is no API to get properties that are nested in other objects"

Comment: @Veverke I guess the idea is that you should know with what kind of data you're working with. Which makes sense.

Comment: I disagree. I mean, what you saying is ideally what should happen, but what about receiving or working with third party objects where you have no knowledge of their structure (and do not want to know) ?

Comment: Guys, please keep in mind that, as a developer, all I asked was: "hey, this problem occurs too many times for us not to automate its solution." It is irrelevant whether you should know the object structure or not, whether you are working with oranges or bananas, is it a problem that frequently enough? Can the solution be put in an algorithm ? Do I have a programming language that can put the algorithm in practice ? Bingo, thank you computers !

Comment: @Veverke I understand your point of view, but i don't think this is the place to start a debate. You should raise an issue on [underscore's github repository](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore), and fork it to add your recursive _.has implementation. Then make that new version available to your dependency management system until underscore eventually accept your pull request on the official repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you:

_.has(o.c,"d")

Comment: Hiren' that's good if I know `o`'s properties in advance. But I was thinking of a solution to when you do not know.